# Add red minus to tableview cell to logout of facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, uitableview

I have a cell that has the name and picture of the facebook user. What I want is to have a red minus on the right of the cell so that when I tap it, a red logout button appears. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the table to editing mode:
`[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:BOOL];`